# Jquery ScrollTop animation issue

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create single page with "move up" and "move down" buttons, which will scroll window to next or previous section (div). Method, which I use is simple. For example I have 5  elements with special ids. I create an array with name "pos" using jquery, where I hold all  elements' positions. Clicking to "move up" and "move down" buttons I check this array and if it contains  position with lower or higher value - window scrolls.
I created jfiddle, so you can check this example here - http://jsfiddle.net/YbqAB/
It works on jfiddle site, but on my page "move down" button doesn't scroll window when $(window).scrollTop() value equals to current  position, even if exist next  position. This issue is not constant - I refrest page (CTRL + F5) a lot of times and sometimes I see this issue, sometimes not.
So, for example if I have 4 div with positions: 0px, 300px, 500px, 800px and when I'm clicking "move down" button, window successfully scrolls to div with 300px. But when I'm clicking to "move down" button once again to move to next div with 500px position - nothing happens. IF I scroll window with my mouse wheel, just few pixels down, "move down" button works well again and scrolls window to div with 500px. 
What I did wrong? Or maybe anyone knows more simple solution. Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <div id="top-button"> up </div>
    <div id="bottom-button"> down </div>
</div>

<div id="position1"> First block </div>
<div id="position2"> Second block </div>
<div id="position3"> Third block </div>
<div id="position4"> Fourth block </div>
<div id="position5"> Fifth block </div>
```

CSS:

```
#buttons{
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    top: 50%;
}

#top-button,
#bottom-button{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: orange;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: yellow;
}

#position1,
#position2,
#position3,
#position4,
#position5{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background: green;
    border-bottom: 5px solid yellow;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Jquery:

```
var pos = [ 
    0,
    $("#position2").offset().top, 
    $("#position3").offset().top, 
    $("#position4").offset().top,
    $("#position5").offset().top
];

var $root = $('html, body');
var current;

$("#buttons #top-button").click(function () {
    $.each(pos, function(i,v){
        if( v < $(window).scrollTop() ){
            current = v;
        }
    });
    $root.stop(true,true).animate({scrollTop:current},500);         
});

$("#buttons #bottom-button").click(function () {
    $.each( pos, function(i,v){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() < v  ){
            $root.stop( true,true ).animate( {scrollTop: v}, 500);
            return false;
        }
    });         
});
```

Comment: it looks to me like you did everything right... works just fine in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes browsers work with pixels that are `0px < val px < 1px`.

My guess would be that the jquery animate scrolls to a value eg. `window.scrollTop = 499.9` while the destination is `500`.

Therefore  `if( $(window).scrollTop() < v  ){` evaluates to the same as before.

To check this you could replace

```
   $root.stop(true,true).animate({scrollTop: v},500);
```

with

```
    $root.stop(true,true).animate({scrollTop: v},500, function(){console.log($(window).scrollTop());});
```

To see the resulting `scrollTop` value, and to check if this is the problem.

But since I cannot reproduce your problem this is still a guess.

Other than that, I'd recommend debugging through your handlers, to see when the scroll is triggered, and find out why it does what it does.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was in pos array values. scrollTop returns an integer, but values of div positions, which I've got with .offset().top are decimal. I tried Math.round() and I think right now everything works fine. Thanks for a tip.

Comment: If somebody else has the same issue where the .scrollTop() returns a decimal, I solved this issue the same way @user13250 suggested. 

`var position=Math.round($("#editScroll").scrollTop());`